# How to form bar chart by using json object

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

i am trying to form a bar chart by using below json object. But, i am unable to form a bar chart 
Can any one please tell me what is the wrong in the below object

```
var data = {
    "nag": {
        "name": "madhu",
        "qfy": "mca",
        "year": 2011
    },
    "kiran": {
        "name": "thirapthi",
        "qfy": "mca",
        "year": 2011
    },
    "reddy": {
        "name": "reddy",
        "qfy": "mca",
        "year": 2011
    }
}

d3.json("Data.json", function(data) {
    var s = Object.keys(data);
    s.forEach(function(keys) {
        var s1 = Object.keys(data[keys]);
        s1.forEach(function(value) {
            var value = data[keys][value];


            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("height", 500)
                .attr("width", 500)
            var svg = canvas.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(s)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return d.value;
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                    return i;
                })
                .attr("width", function(d, i) {
                    return i * 5;
                })
                .style("fill", "blue");
        })

    })
});
```

Comment: For starters, all your rendering code (starting with `var canvas = ...`) is inside the nested `forEach` loop, so instead of running once, it runs 9 times. And each time it runs, `s` is the same thing: just an array of keys `["nag", "kiran", "reddy"]` with no values. You should move the rendering out of the loop, so it runs only once. Then use your browser's developer tools and `console.log(s)` and debug it so that you're building the data structure you expect to build.

Comment: i am also trying that way but enable to show the bars in browser